# Do not understand how the router hash changes in this example code [backbone.js]

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Here is the example code
https://github.com/derickbailey/todomvc/tree/marionette/labs/architecture-examples/backbone_marionette

This example code is run here
http://todomvc.com/labs/architecture-examples/backbone_marionette/#

I cannot figure out how the route changes when the filter is clicked. I've been going over this so many times, but I cannot seem to understand how the route itself changes when the filter is clicked. All I see are the functions that are called when the route changes, but not the actual route change itself.

For example, when the current filter is on "All", and I click "Completed", how does the URL change to #completed?

Any insight would be great

Thanks

Comment: Ehem, it's a simple link I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply an anchor tag that has it's href as `#` `#active` and `#completed`.

Comment: That's embarrassing. I was concentrating so hard on the javascript I forgot about the html. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes the most obvious answer is the last one that you look for :)